# Using rep points from another site for a bounty, should this be allowed here?

Tags: discussion, features, reputation, bounty, stackexchange

First off I know that StackExchange does not allow one to use reputation points of one site to be used for a bounty on another site. That is the goal I am hoping for but want some feeback before possibly making the request.

See: [Can I use rep on one site to set a bounty on another?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252924/1243762)

The request was also put forward and declined.

See: [Allow bounty to be set with reputation from another site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7193)

How the idea and desire came about is that I am trying to learn enough category theory to make practical use of it instead of just reading about it to gain some insight, so naturally I need to work with it on some practical problems. And thus will be asking basic questions, but want to pull in more people for possibly better answers by offering a bounty when necessary.

Now it has become obvious that there are three Stack Exchange sites that give answers for Category Theory:
 [Computer Sciecne](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) ([questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/category-theory))
 [Computer Science Theory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) ([questions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ct.category-theory))
 [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) ([questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/category-theory))

yet I only have enough [rep](http://stackexchange.com/users/1291795/guy-coder?tab=accounts) in StackOveflow and Computer Science that I would consider using. I am sure there are others in the same position.

I would actually like to post the bounties on the CSTheory site but I have no significant history there as I do here and I know most of the people who respond here also are on CSTheory.

While I would like the sharing of rep points between sites to be unconstrained, I would settle for a constraint of similar tags. i.e. if more than one site has a similar tag, then one can ask the question on another site with a similar tag and use rep points from a different site for the bounty in the other site.

So the question (discussion) is, should the rep points for a bounty be allowed to be taken from user's rep points of a different Stack Exchange site?

Comment: Maintaining any reasonable sets of constraints would likely be a nightmare. In any case, being able to transport reputation from "low hanging fruit"-land to "high-hanging-fruit"-land strikes me as very invasive w.r.t. to the little game we have running.

Comment: I have been away from the site for a few months, what are you referring to as the little game?

Comment: The whole reputation business, of course!

Comment: Oh, I thought the we in "game we have" as being limited to just you and me. Makes sense now. I do dislike the game. Makes me want to go off and create a different site without the game, but I am sure eventually these sites will only be available via the [Way back machine](https://archive.org/web/web.php).

Comment: @Raphael Here is the CSTheory [question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/25099/8739) So what was once low hanging fruit for me and is now high hanging fruit for me could become your low hanging fruit. It's all in the way you view it. Maybe there is a rep morphism and we can turn Stack Exchange into a category.

Comment: I was rather assuming that some [cstheory.SE] users may view [cs.SE] as "low-hanging". In fact, you *could* instrument reputation points earned by answering homework dumps on [cs.SE] or [math.SE] for shaping [cstheory.SE] (by gaining privileges and voting, ...). I'm pretty sure that this is not in the spirit of SE as it is.

Comment: Regarding "the game", one does not have to like the struggle for points, but the fact remains that it *works*. For some weird reason, these abstract, worthless numbers seem to instill the motivation to provide quality answers (in many).

Comment: I have considered answering homework dump questions but I think it brings the site down to a lower level when the question is not properly asked. I don't like having to close many questions, especially to new comers, but if a standard is not maintained, those with the answers I need might leave. I too don't like the points but at present it seems to be the mechanism by which one can potentially identify those who know what they are talking about and those that give answers to earn points.

Comment: Late comment to clarify: my "could" was not intended to suggest you do that but rather paint a scenario that would be made possible by your scenario but would harm [cstheory.SE] (and [cs.SE] along the way, as you note).